# apache reverse proxy and url with hash character

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I've a problem with an apache reverse proxy. the application in backend that I've to proxy has some rule of this kind

```
https://example.org/example#/test
```

when reversing this kind of url apache strips everything beyond the # character.

so I have only reversed

```
https://example.org/example
```

I've done some researches and it seems normal since the #character is an anchor and is used by browser to anchor the document.
Is there a way to bypass this behaviour without modification on the backend application?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "anchor" part of the URL - e.g. everything past the `#` sign - is *never* sent back to the server.

> Is there a way to bypass this behaviour without modification on the backend application?

There is *no way* to bypass this behavior without modification *of how the browser* handles this connection. The server (neither the reverse proxy nor any webserver) never sees this part of the URL.

(the server might *respond* with an anchored `<a href.../>` URL to the client, but *never* will see a *request* back with the anchored URL content in question. The browsers, by design, never send that part)